# pythonでCSVファイルを読み込む関数がエラーを起こします。

Tags: python, csv

pythonでCSVファイルを読み込む関数を作ろうとしているのですけれど何故か変なエラーが出ます。これを改善する方法はありませんか？

```
def csv_input(csv):
    data = []
    f = open(csv, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
    return data

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "makes.py", line 70, in input_datas
  data = csv.reader(f)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

こんなエラーが出ます。何故出るのかわかりません。

Answer (score 9):

引数の `csv` と `csvモジュール` の名前が衝突してます。

`reader = csv.reader(f)` は「`csv` モジュールの `reader()`」を呼び出しているつもりかもしれませんが「引数 `csv` の `reader()`」を呼び出しているので `'str' object has no attribute 'reader'` というエラーになります。